# Appending dataframe extracted from Page#2,3,4,5 ...to dataframe extracted from Page#1 of coingecko in Pandas python using a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm practicing python pandas and trying to extract the first 500 coins from coingecko into one dataframe. Each page in coingecko has 100 coins. I am able to extract the dataframes from each page by changing the page# in the url..I tried using df1.append(df2) by using a for loop over the page numbers but that didn't work. What am i doing wrong?

I need one dataframe with all 500 coins

```
def get_coingecko_data(): 
    page_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5] 
    for n in page_numbers: 
        r = requests.get(f"https://www.coingecko.com/?page={n}") 
        df = pd.read_html(r.text)[0] 
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(df) 
        df2 = df2[["#", "Coin", "Price", "Mkt Cap"]] 
        if n == 1: 
            df_500 = df2.copy() 
        else:
            df_500.append(df4, ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a couple of issues. First the last line has a typo, it should be `df2` not `df4`.

The second problem you have is that contrary to the behaviour of the python append, the `pandas.DataFrame.append` does not change the object but rather returns the result of the append as such you would have to rewrite the last line as

```
df_500 = df_500.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
```

It is for this quite common confusion among others that `append` has been deprecated since v1.4 and it is now recommended to switch to `pandas.concat`

Last but not least your function lacks a return.

Fixing all of the above reults in the function

```
def get_coingecko_data(): 
    page_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5] 
    for n in page_numbers: 
        r = requests.get(f"https://www.coingecko.com/?page={n}") 
        df = pd.read_html(r.text)[0] 
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(df) 
        df2 = df2[["#", "Coin", "Price", "Mkt Cap"]] 
        if n == 1: 
            df_500 = df2.copy() 
        else:
            df_500 = pd.concat([df_500, df2], ignore_index = True)
    return df_500
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the equal sign to update `df_500` variable.

```
df_500 = df_500.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

**By the way here is a cleaner version:**

```
def get_coingecko_data():
    page_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    df500 = pd.DataFrame()

    for n in page_numbers:
        r = requests.get(f"https://www.coingecko.com/?page={n}")
        dfPre = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]
        df500 = df500.append(dfPre[["#", "Coin", "Price", "Mkt Cap"]], ignore_index=True)
```